# How to increase number of hexagons in a responsive grid row?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have took reference from https://codepen.io/web-tiki/pen/HhCyd to create responsive hexagon grid. I have tweeted them according to my requirement.It takes only 5 hexagons in one row at the start depending upon the screen size according to some calculation in style.css file.Please help me out to increase the hexagons in a row and reduce the size of the hexagon shape.Here's the jsfiddle for the same. https://jsfiddle.net/fmuthewk/
Thanks in advance !

```
<ul id="categories" class="clr">
        <li>
            <div>
                <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 200.91789367798975 232" style="filter: drop-shadow(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.498039) 0px 0px 10px);">
                    <path stroke="grey" stroke-width="5" fill="none" d="M79.67433714816835 11.999999999999998Q100.45894683899488 0 121.2435565298214 12L180.13328398716322 46Q200.91789367798975 58 200.91789367798975 82L200.91789367798975 150Q200.91789367798975 174 180.13328398716322 186L121.2435565298214 220Q100.45894683899488 232 79.67433714816835 220L20.784609690826528 186Q0 174 0 150L0 82Q0 58 20.784609690826528 46Z">
                    </path>
                </svg>
                <h1 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myFirstModal">This is a title</h1>
                <p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myFirstModal">Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>
                <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="201" height="232" viewbox="0 0 200.91789367798975 232" style="filter: drop-shadow(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.498039) 0px 0px 10px);">
                    <path fill="#9C27B0" d="M79.67433714816835 11.999999999999998Q100.45894683899488 0 121.2435565298214 12L180.13328398716322 46Q200.91789367798975 58 200.91789367798975 82L200.91789367798975 150Q200.91789367798975 174 180.13328398716322 186L121.2435565298214 220Q100.45894683899488 232 79.67433714816835 220L20.784609690826528 186Q0 174 0 150L0 82Q0 58 20.784609690826528 46Z"></path>
                </svg>
                <h1 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mySecondModal">This is a title</h1>
                <p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mySecondModal">Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div>
                <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="201" height="232" viewbox="0 0 200.91789367798975 232" style="filter: drop-shadow(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.498039) 0px 0px 10px);">
                    <path fill="#C51162" d="M79.67433714816835 11.999999999999998Q100.45894683899488 0 121.2435565298214 12L180.13328398716322 46Q200.91789367798975 58 200.91789367798975 82L200.91789367798975 150Q200.91789367798975 174 180.13328398716322 186L121.2435565298214 220Q100.45894683899488 232 79.67433714816835 220L20.784609690826528 186Q0 174 0 150L0 82Q0 58 20.784609690826528 46Z"></path>
                </svg>
                <h1 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myThirdModal">This is a title</h1>
                <p data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myThirdModal">Some sample text about the article this hexagon leads to</p>
            </div>
        </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Just play around with CSS/SVG parameters

Comment: #categories li {
        width: 17.364%;
        /* = (100-4.5) / 5.5 */
        padding-bottom: 20.05%;
        /* =  width /0.866 */
    }
    #categories li:nth-child(10n+6),
    #categories li:nth-child(10n+7),
    #categories li:nth-child(10n+8),
    #categories li:nth-child(10n+9),
    #categories li:nth-child(10n+10) {
        margin-top: -4.2%;
        margin-bottom: -4.2%;
        transform: translateX(50%) rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    } 
I tried changing these values but the whole grid structure breaks.